# Why is this iframe (youtube embed) behaving differently in chrome and ie?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, bxslider

I am embedding youtube iframes in a bxslider.  When you go from slide to slide, the iframe remains in position on top of everything in ie for some reason.

Behaviour in chrome (for same html and css) is what I want!

Please see link: www.torontochinesesoccer.com/brands

The divs (including the one the video is inside) are all relatively positioned.  Does ie treat iframes differently??

Answer (score 0):

try use wmode="Opaque" on your iframe or you can use jquery code

```
  $('iframe').each(function()
     {var url = $(this).attr("src");
      var result = url.search(/youtube/i);
      if(result!=-1)
       {result = url.indexOf('?');
        if(result!=-1)  
          {$(this).attr("src",url+"&wmode=transparent");
          } else {$(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent");}
       }
     });
      });
```

you can find more here - http://www.scorchsoft.com/news/youtube-z-index-embed-iframe-fix